# UI-Router does not register history before $onInit

Tags: angularjs, meteor, oauth-2.0, angular-ui-router, angular-meteor

So I have a login scheme that only needs user login behind specific pages. Currently, I have the page checking if the user exists via the $onInit function, then firing the login (which redirects to a login page via Code Flow in OAuth 2). Then when I've logged in, the page redirects back to the previous page, instead of the page I fired the login even from.

I think this is due to ui-router not registering history with the browser before it redirects, thus the $state object in the OAuth 2 parameters, when decoded shows me the path: "redirectUrl":"http://localhost:3000/reservations" when it should be "redirectUrl":"http://localhost:3000/reservations/purchase".

So my question is two fold.

1. Is $onInit an appropriate place to be doing this, or should I have some global routechange listener or use resolve? If I use either of those two methods, I think I will still have the route problem.
2. If I keep using $onInit, is there some way to make sure the url is registered correctly so that it will redirect to the correct location post-login?

$onInit function:

```
function init() {
    var token = Meteor.call('getAccessToken');
    if (!token) {
        Meteor.loginWithOidc();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that the problem is that $onInit is called too early when url is not registered yet. When a controller is called, everything else is already set up. Yes, a resolver is the best place to handle this.

Comment: If I handle it in the resolver, would the redirect correctly register the page or would I have a similar problem? Also, if calling this function in $onInit isn't the problem any idea what is?

Comment: Don't have an answer here, sorry. It can be a router bug after all. Any way, a proper reproduction of the problem is required, as a plunker or somehow. Since it is Meteor app, I guess the app should be truncated first to bare minimum. It is likely that you will figure out what was wrong when doing that.

Comment: @estus this is a little late, but as I tried to reduce it to bare minimum in order to create a plunkr I realized that there were some issues with the package I was using when creating redirect URLS, so it wasn't an issue with $onInit after all. Thanks!

Comment: That's ok. Most problems solve themselves during reproduction process.